# How can i get Audio Stream input as binary number for AES encryption in verilog?

Tags: matlab, cryptography, aes, verilog, fpga

I am doing a project in which I have written the code for AES-128 encryption algorithm in Verilog with a fixed input (128-bit), Now I want to take audio stream as binary number and use it for input to AES encryption algorithm.
What would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in figure, Connect your source of Audio to ADC, Make sampling frequency as described in below,

`F_sample >= 2 x Fmax_audio` (According to Nyquist Criteria)

That will be fed to ADC.

Give 90 degree shifted clock to FPGA for latching that Digital data from ADC.

Now you have your data on Board, use it in AES algorithm.

You can do reverse process to speaker.

[image]

- 180 degree phase shift also can be used, according to setup and hold time.

Edit:

There is one reason why 90 degree phase shifted clock to FPGA board, if we use 90 degree phase shifted clock then it is sampling the data at half of positive level, so we can avoid the mis-sample. See image, at 90 degree it is stable as well, we also can use 180 degree.

[image]

Comment: I think we can have a greater-than-or-equals-to (`>=`) for sampling frequency (`F_sample >= 2 x Fmax_audio`, Nyquist criteria). I assume ADC produces 128-bit output (which I think is a reasonable assumption). Can you please elaborate why the 90-degree phase shift?

Comment: Oh! Yes, You are right. See edit. I never heard about 128 bit ADC, can you please tell me that IC?

Comment: Since the OP has fixed 128-bit input to AES, thereby I assumed that the ADC in diagram provides 128-bit output. That was just an off-the-track discussion out of curiosity. Thanks.

Comment: Oh Yes! @sharvil111, but OP has to do internal mechanism for that.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the inputs.